# How to loop through XML using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML document using XSLT.  I have got so far but I can't get the grouping level correct.  I want each of the ASN numbers to have there own section.  I've tried placing the For loops at different locations but no joy.

XML:-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders>
 <Order>
  <och_contract>FO</och_contract>
  <SourceLocation>W235X</SourceLocation>
  <SourceLocationName>ARMSTRONG FASENINGS LTD</SourceLocationName>
  <DestinationLocation>3C</DestinationLocation>
  <och_type>P</och_type>
  <CollectionDate>20170814</CollectionDate>
  <Customer_Ref>FO-323296</Customer_Ref>
  <Plan_m3>3.60</Plan_m3>
  <Plan_Kgs>2500.00</Plan_Kgs>
  <Actual_M3>0.00</Actual_M3>
  <Actual_Kgs>0.00</Actual_Kgs>
  <och_trip_ref>IBHC0141733001H</och_trip_ref>
  <ASN_Numbers>
   <ASN>STU1234</ASN>
   <ASN>STU2345</ASN>
   <ASN>STU3456</ASN>
  </ASN_Numbers>
 </Order>
 <Order>
  <och_contract>FO</och_contract>
  <SourceLocation>A07LA</SourceLocation>
  <SourceLocationName>STOKES GROUP LTD</SourceLocationName>
  <DestinationLocation>3C</DestinationLocation>
  <och_type>P</och_type>
  <CollectionDate>20170817</CollectionDate>
  <Customer_Ref>FO-323430</Customer_Ref>
  <Plan_m3>2.88</Plan_m3>
  <Plan_Kgs>2500.00</Plan_Kgs>
  <Actual_M3>5.40</Actual_M3>
  <Actual_Kgs>14782.00</Actual_Kgs>
  <och_trip_ref>IBHC0491733004H</och_trip_ref>
  <ASN_Numbers>
   <ASN>ANDY1234</ASN>
   <ASN>ANDY2345</ASN>
   <ASN>ASN3456</ASN>
  </ASN_Numbers>
 </Order>
</Orders>
```

XSLT:-

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm file:///C:/Users/andfishe/Documents/Projects/OTM%20Training/OTM/GLogXML_6.3.xsd">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<INVOICE>
   <xsl:call-template name="Invoice"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="Shipment"/>
</INVOICE>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Invoice">
<CARRIER_GSDB>V0K2Q</CARRIER_GSDB>
<INV_REF>6L027195</INV_REF>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Shipment">
<xsl:for-each select="Orders/Order">
<SHIPMENT>
<BILL_CURR>GBX</BILL_CURR>
 <STOP_GSDB>
  <xsl:value-of select="SourceLocation"/>
 </STOP_GSDB>
 
 <STOP_NAME>
  <xsl:value-of select="SourceLocationName"/>
 </STOP_NAME>
  <LINE_ITEM>
   <xsl:for-each select="ASN_Numbers">
    <ASN>
     <ASN_REF>
      <xsl:value-of select="ASN"/>
     </ASN_REF>
    </ASN>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </LINE_ITEM>
 
</SHIPMENT>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output:-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOICE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <CARRIER_GSDB>V0K2Q</CARRIER_GSDB>
 <INV_REF>6L027195</INV_REF>
 <SHIPMENT>
  <BILL_CURR>GBX</BILL_CURR>
  <STOP_GSDB>W235X</STOP_GSDB>
  <STOP_NAME>ARMSTRONG FASENINGS LTD</STOP_NAME>
  <LINE_ITEM>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>STU1234 STU2345 STU3456</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
  </LINE_ITEM>
 </SHIPMENT>
 <SHIPMENT>
  <BILL_CURR>GBX</BILL_CURR>
  <STOP_GSDB>A07LA</STOP_GSDB>
  <STOP_NAME>STOKES GROUP LTD</STOP_NAME>
  <LINE_ITEM>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>ANDY1234 ANDY2345 ASN3456</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
  </LINE_ITEM>
 </SHIPMENT>
</INVOICE>
```

I would like the LINE_ITEM section to look like:-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOICE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <CARRIER_GSDB>V0K2Q</CARRIER_GSDB>
 <INV_REF>6L027195</INV_REF>
 <SHIPMENT>
  <BILL_CURR>GBX</BILL_CURR>
  <STOP_GSDB>W235X</STOP_GSDB>
  <STOP_NAME>ARMSTRONG FASENINGS LTD</STOP_NAME>
  <LINE_ITEM>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>STU1234</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>STU2345</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>STU3456</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
  </LINE_ITEM>
 </SHIPMENT>
 <SHIPMENT>
  <BILL_CURR>GBX</BILL_CURR>
  <STOP_GSDB>A07LA</STOP_GSDB>
  <STOP_NAME>STOKES GROUP LTD</STOP_NAME>
  <LINE_ITEM>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>ANDY1234</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>ANDY2345</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
   <ASN>
    <ASN_REF>ASN3456</ASN_REF>
   </ASN>
  </LINE_ITEM>
 </SHIPMENT>
</INVOICE>
```

Does anybody know how to acheive this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        <LINE_ITEM>
        <xsl:for-each select="ASN_Numbers/ASN">
            <ASN>
                <ASN_REF>                           
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </ASN_REF>
            </ASN>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </LINE_ITEM>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ASN_Numbers">
    <ASN>
        <ASN_REF>
            <xsl:value-of select="ASN"/>
        </ASN_REF>
    </ASN>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ASN_Numbers/ASN">
    <ASN>
        <ASN_REF>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </ASN_REF>
    </ASN>
</xsl:for-each>
```